# Merge Uneven Dataframes - Performance

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two uneven datasets that I want to merge.

Just for the record, the data is about users (who have an ID), and user sessions (which also have an ID). Since each user can have many sessions, each user ID can appear many times. So, the only unique identifier is a combination of User ID, and session ID. (Shortly, the user ID is unique among users, but ambiguous among user-sessions).

So, df1, contains information about each session ('unique_id'). Among this information, is also the user's id ('ambig id'). Now, there is another dataframe (df2), which contains information about users (values1, values2).

So, I want, in the session-based df (df1), to add the user-information from df2.
The example dataframes are as following:

**df1**

```
   ambig_id unique_id
0         1       1.1
1         2       2.1
2         3       3.1
3         4       4.1
4         1       1.2
5         2       2.2
6         3       3.2
7         4       4.2
```

**df2**

```
   ambig_id  values1  values2
0         1      101      201
1         2      102      202
2         3      103      203
3         4      104      204
4         5      105      205
5         6      106      206
6         7      107      207
7         8      108      208
8         9      109      209
9        10      110      210
```

**desired_df**

```
   ambig_id unique_id  values1  values2
0         1       1.1      101      201
1         2       2.1      102      202
2         3       3.1      103      203
3         4       4.1      104      204
4         1       1.2      101      201
5         2       2.2      102      202
6         3       3.2      103      203
7         4       4.2      104      204
```

I have managed to do so, by pd.merge_ordered:

```
test_df = pd.merge_ordered(df1,df2,left_by='ambig_id')
```

But it seems slow for large datasets. Is there any ideas on how to improve performance on this task?

(Below the code for the example dataframes)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ambig_id':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 'unique_id':['1.1', '2.1', '3.1', '4.1', '1.2', '2.2', '3.2', '4.2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ambig_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                              'values1':[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110],
                              'values2': [201, 202, 203, 204, 205,206, 207, 208, 209, 210]})

desired_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ambig_id':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                                     'unique_id':['1.1', '2.1', '3.1', '4.1', '1.2', '2.2', '3.2', '4.2'],
                                     'values1': [101,102,103,104,101,102,103,104],
                                    'values2': [201, 202, 203, 204,201, 202, 203, 204]})
```

Comment: Maybe if you set `ambig_id` as index. `pd.merge(df1.set_index('ambig_id'), df2.set_index('ambig_id'), on='ambig_id', how='left')`

Answer (score 1):

I think simple left-merge should work for you, (works for the sample data and expected output):

```py
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='left')

   ambig_id  unique_id  values1  values2
0         1        1.1      101      201
1         2        2.1      102      202
2         3        3.1      103      203
3         4        4.1      104      204
4         1        1.2      101      201
5         2        2.2      102      202
6         3        3.2      103      203
7         4        4.2      104      204
```